# Access periodically changing file with get request

Tags: node.js, express

So basically I have this part in app.js.

```
const app = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const Index = require('./routes/index');
const getData = require('./db/data').getData;
const app=express();

app.use('/getData',Index);

setInterval(() => {
    getData(false).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data[1]);
        fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('awritten');
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}, 60000);
```

getData is manually defined promise which resolves properly.

The getData route is as follows

```
route.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    var data = require('../data.json').data;
    res.send(data);
});
```

data.json file is already created in root directory of the App.

My question is whenever I start the app and use the given route, it gives response as intended but when the file is changed periodically ('awritten' is logged on console per minute) in seInterval function, the change doesn't reflect in the getData route even after reloading... Everytime I have to restart the app to reflect changes.ie The only initial data in the file can be viewed... not after the file has been changed. Is there any way to get real time data from data.json without restarting the express server?

Edit : Got the solution. used fs to readfile on every get request.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a thing. 
used fs to readfile on every get request and it worked as expected.